# How to replace a specific position of a main grid (array of arrays)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, minesweeper

I'm coding a minesweeper and I got the UI and I can't modify it. I've made the grid for different sizes but now I need to push the mines into it, I created a function that gives me an array of mines in differents positions taking as parameter the boardsize, but I cant figure how push this array of mines into the grid replacing the cells if it match with mines position

Here is the code:

```
import { CellEnum } from "../types";
import { CellComponentType } from "../UI/components/CellComponentType";
import { getMinePositions, positionMatch } from "./mines";

export function def(boardSize: number, minesInGame: number) {
let board: CellEnum[][] = [];
const minePosition = getMinePositions(boardSize, minesInGame);
for (let xAxis = 0; xAxis < boardSize; xAxis++) {
const row = [];

for (let yAxis = 0; yAxis < boardSize; yAxis++) {
  let tile: CellEnum = CellEnum.Hidden

  

  row.push(tile);
}
board.push(row);
}
return board;
}
```

And this is the code of mines generator

```
import { CellComponentType } from "../UI/components/CellComponentType";
import { CellEnum } from "../types";

function randomNumber(size: number) {
return Math.floor(Math.random() * size);
}

function positionMatch(a: CellComponentType, b: CellComponentType) {
return a.position === b.position;
}
function getMinePositions(boardSize: number, minesInGame: number) {
const positions: CellComponentType[] = [];

while (positions.length < minesInGame) {
let position: CellComponentType = {
  position: [randomNumber(boardSize), randomNumber(boardSize)],
  cell: CellEnum.Mine
};

if (!positions.some(positionMatch.bind(null, position))) {
  positions.push(position);
}
}

return positions;
}

export { getMinePositions, positionMatch };
```

CellComponentType has this attributes:

```
type CellComponentType = {
position: [number, number];
cell: CellEnum;
};
```

And finally these are the different status that could have a cell

```
enum CellEnum {
Hidden = -1,
Cero = 0,
One = 1,
Two = 2,
Three = 3,
Four = 4,
Five = 5,
Six = 6,
Seven = 7,
Eight = 8,
Flag = 9,
Mine = 10,
ClickedMine = 11
}
```

I really appreciate if someone could help, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem in your `positionMatch`-method. You are comparing the array itself when you actually want to compare the content of the array. Change your method like this:

```js
function positionMatch(a: CellComponentType, b: CellComponentType) {
    return a.position[0] === b.position[0]
        && a.position[1] === b.position[1];
}
```

To add the mines to the field you can loop over your mine positions and overwrite the matching hidden fields before returning the board:

```js
for(let mine of minePosition) {
    board[mine.position[1], mine.position[0]] = mine.cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the mines and change the corresponding board tile:

```
const mines = getMinePositions();

mines.forEach((mine) => {
    const [x, y] = mine.position;

    board[y][x] = mine.cell;
});
```

I don't know how you've got your board setup but usually I have it as `y` as rows and `x` as columns, so I've used `board[y][x]` here.

Comment: Ok, I got it, this loop should be write after return board, I mean, following that logic the board should be complete and after that I could make a loop over the mines from the board, right?

Comment: @KevinHernandez Yes I believe so. You can also make this another function as well if you need to use this more than once.